# Looping back to command C++

Tags: c++, compare

I have thought of a very simple program that loops back to the "command" function if one enters a wrong command.
Before continuing development of a text-based rpg game and using this as my base, I'd like to know whether it is a bad idea to include the majority of main as a while loop as I've done below, or whether there's a more simple way to recall the function and place the user back at the top of main to check for string comparison without using the "goto" option? Thank you very much in anticipation!

```
std::string command()
{
    std::string input;
    std::cout << "$home: ";
    std::cin >> input;
    return input;
}

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (!command().compare("help"))
        {
            std::cout << "Command HELP exists!\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "You have entered an unrecognized command.\n";
        }
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: your Else is not necessary since if the If is not entered it will do another loop right away.

Comment: I've changed a little bit of the code to make it more clear. It'll always loop back to the beginning as the player enters the next command after the initial one has been executed. Need the else to state whether the command exists. Is this bad practice? Don't normally use 'while true' but in this case I think it works okay.

Comment: It's debatable really, depends on people. It's acceptable if you really want to say that your program can run infinitely. If you think it needs an exit condition then it should be changed (like the exit command).

Comment: @DeanHampson The `continue;` is superfluous.

Comment: Lmao thanks Pei! That is true indeed. Removed x)

Comment: Yeah Dart, I'll add an "exit" command and break out of the loop with that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Obviously your example is very simplistic (e.g. you need to provide some kind of “exit” command), but the pattern it shows is completely fine. A loop like this is the essence of what game developers usually call the “game loop” and GUI programmers call the “event loop”. It’s a fundamental pattern for every program that needs to keep running until explicitely told to stop in contrast to doing its work and then ending automatically.

As your program grows you’ll have some startup code before the main loop and some teardown code afterwards and the loop itself will probably move from `main()` to another file. Here’s a barebones example using the Qt framework that shows a GUI main loop.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <MainWindow.hpp>

int main()
{
    QApplication app;
    MainWindow win;
    win.show();
    return app.exec();  // <-- main loop happens here
}
```

Offtopic: About the

```
if (!command().compare("help"))
```

line … Lines like these *really* bug me. ;) Don’t write it that way! It’s extremely misleading because intuitively – and especially when scanning the code quickly – it reads: *If command is not "help" then "Command HELP exists!"*; and the natural reaction is: WTF!? Always spell out the value you’re comparing against to make it clear what’s happening:

```
if (command().compare("help") == 0) // ...
```

Or event better, since in this case all the information you need is equal or not:

```
if (command() == "help") // ...
```

Comment: I'd remove the Offtopic part. It is totally opinion based. The way he wrote it is a totally acceptable and easy to read.